# Simple memory game doesn't update its state. Bad game loop?

Tags: javascript, game-loop

I'm trying to make a simple (or so I thought) memory game. Unfortunately it does not update state of cards when user clicks on them. I'm running out of ideas, probably because it's my first javascript game. I suppose there is a problem with game loop. Could anyone at least point me in the right direction and help me understand what needs to be changed/rewritten?

```
//HTML5 Memory Game implementation

//main variables
var cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var exposed = [makeArray("false",16)];
var first_card = 0;
var second_card = 0;
var moves = 0;
var WIDTH = 800;
var HEIGHT = 100;
var state = 0;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

//creating canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = WIDTH;
canvas.height = HEIGHT;
document.getElementById("game").appendChild(canvas);

//filling empty array with number,character,object
function makeArray(value, length) {
    var newArray = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i<length) {
        newArray[i] = value;
        i++;
    }
    return newArray;
}

//shuffling algorithm
function shuffle(array) {
    var copy = [];
    var n = array.length;
    var i;

    while (n) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * n--);
        copy.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }

    return copy;
}

//where user clicks
function getClickPosition(event) {
    var X = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var Y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    return mouse = [X, Y];
}

//read click position
function readPos(event) {
    mousePos = getClickPosition(event);
    mouseX = mousePos[0];
    mouseY = mousePos[1];
}

//initializing
function init() {
    state = 0;
    moves = 0;
    exposed = [makeArray("false",16)];
    cards = shuffle(cards);
}

//drawing cards
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for (var i in cards) {
        if (exposed[i] === true) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
            ctx.font = "50px Courier New";
            ctx.fillText(cards[i], (i*50+12), 65);
        } else {
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(250, 0, 0)";
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 250)";
            ctx.fillRect(i*50, 0, 50, 100);
            ctx.strokeRect(i*50, 0, 50, 100);
        }
    }
};

//update cards
function update() {
    if (exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] === false) {
        if (state == 0) {
            state = 1;
            first_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
            exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
        } else if (state == 1) {
            state = 2;
            second_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
            exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
        } else {
            if (cards[first_card] != cards[second_card]) {
                exposed[first_card] = false;
                exposed[second_card] = false;
            }
            state = 1;
            first_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
            exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
        }
    }
}

addEventListener('click', readPos, false);

setInterval(function() {
    update();
    draw();
}, 16);
```

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to step through the code and see what happens when you click? You'll have to do that first and narrow your question to the part of the code that doesn't work as expected. This process should probably lead you to the solution anyways since it's probably trivial. Good luck!

Comment: Check if your click event is actually fired (e.g. put a breakpoint in it or put a console.log in it with some relevant data). I doubt it is necessary to have an interval of 16ms; This might create a backlog. Does the situation improve if you make the interval bigger (say 200ms)? You might even want to reconsider making a loop and let the click on a card update the interface. If mouseX and mouseY are correctly set, check if update() does access the same variable (e.g. do they have the same value?). If they do, does it translate to the right card (or a card at all?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copy and pasting your code I found a couple of things:

1. You didn't add an event listener to anything, you should add it to something so I added it to document.
2. You initialize the exposed array with values "false" and later check if they are false. These are not the same, the string "false" isn't the Boolean false.
3. You initializes the exposed array as a multi dimensional array [[false,false,false ...]] this should be a single dimension array because later you check exposed[1] (1 depending on the mouse x position.
4. No need to call draw and update every 16 milliseconds, you can call it after someone clicked.
5. Wrapped the whole thing up in a function so there are no global variables created.

Here is the code after changing these obvious errors. There might be room for optimization but for now I've gotten the problems out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>test</title>
</head> 
 <body> 
<div id="game"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     (function(){
         //HTML5 Memory Game implementation

         //main variables
         var cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
         var exposed = makeArray(false, 16);
         var first_card = 0;
         var second_card = 0;
         var moves = 0;
         var WIDTH = 800;
         var HEIGHT = 100;
         var state = 0;
         var mouseX = 0;
         var mouseY = 0;

         //creating canvas
         var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         canvas.width = WIDTH;
         canvas.height = HEIGHT;
         document.getElementById("game").appendChild(canvas);

         //filling empty array with number,character,object
         function makeArray(value, length) {
             var newArray = [];
             var i = 0;
             while (i < length) {
                 newArray.push(value);
                 i++;
             }
             return newArray;
         }

         //shuffling algorithm
         function shuffle(array) {
             var copy = [];
             var n = array.length;
             var i;

             while (n) {
                 i = Math.floor(Math.random() * n--);
                 copy.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
             }

             return copy;
         }

         //where user clicks
         function getClickPosition(event) {
             var X = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
             var Y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
             return mouse = [X, Y];
         }

         //read click position
         function readPos(event) {
             mousePos = getClickPosition(event);
             mouseX = mousePos[0];
             mouseY = mousePos[1];
             update();
             draw();
         }

         //initializing
         function init() {
             state = 0;
             moves = 0;
             exposed = makeArray(false, 16);
             cards = shuffle(cards);
         }

         //drawing cards
         function draw() {
             ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
             for (var i in cards) {
                 if (exposed[i] === true) {
                     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 150, 150)";
                     ctx.font = "50px Courier New";
                     ctx.fillText(cards[i], (i * 50 + 12), 65);
                 } else {
                     ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(250, 0, 0)";
                     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 250)";
                     ctx.fillRect(i * 50, 0, 50, 100);
                     ctx.strokeRect(i * 50, 0, 50, 100);
                 }
             }
         };
         //update cards
         function update() {
             if (exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] === false) {
                 if (state == 0) {
                     state = 1;
                     first_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
                     exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
                 } else if (state == 1) {
                     state = 2;
                     second_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
                     exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
                 } else {
                     if (cards[first_card] != cards[second_card]) {
                         exposed[first_card] = false;
                         exposed[second_card] = false;
                     }
                     state = 1;
                     first_card = parseInt(mouseX / 50);
                     exposed[parseInt(mouseX / 50)] = true;
                 }
             }
         }
         document.body.addEventListener('click', readPos, false);
         init();
         draw();
     })();
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should pay more attention to what I write in the code. I am trying to port that code from Python, so maybe that was the reason too. Is it generally better to wrap everything in a function? Or was it just a precaution?

Comment: @Aplegatt it's just so not all the variables end up in global scope. doesn't realy do anyting but if your code needs to run with other (people's) code than it's generally a good idea not to pollute the global scope. You could wrap the whole thing up in a function called MemGame, define the var's with `this` the functions on the prototype and use it as a constructor to create game object instances http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1):

I would check your addEventListener method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener
I also recommend you look into using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that not assigning event listener to something was one of the problems. Going to read those things more carefully now:)

Answer (score 0):

Your overall logic was good.
The point that was 'bad' was the way you handle the event :
the event handler should store some valuable information that
the update will later process and clear.
Here you mix your update with event handling, which cannot work 
especially since the event will not fire on every update.

So i did a little fiddle to show you, the main change is
the click event handler, which update the var last_clicked_card :

http://jsfiddle.net/wpymH/

```
//read click position
function readPos(event) {
    last_clicked_card = -1;
    mousePos = getClickPosition(event);
    mouseX = mousePos[0];
    mouseY = mousePos[1];
    //  on canvas ?
    if ((mouseY>100)||(mouseX<0)||(mouseX>WIDTH)) return;
    // now yes : which card clicked ?
    last_clicked_card = Math.floor(mouseX/50);
 }
```

and then update is the processing of this information :

```
//update cards
function update() {
    // return if no new card clicked
    if (last_clicked_card == -1) return;
    // read and clear last card clicked
    var newCard = last_clicked_card;
    last_clicked_card=-1;
    // flip, store it as first card and return 
    // if there was no card flipped
    if (state==0) {  exposed[newCard] = true;
                     first_card = newCard; 
                     state = 1 ;
                     return;        }
    // just unflip card if card was flipped
    if ((state = 1) && exposed[newCard]) {     
                     exposed[newCard]=false ;
                     state=0;
                     return;
    }
    // we have a second card now
    second_card = newCard;
    exposed[second_card] =  true;
    draw();
    // ... i don't know what you want to do ...
    if (cards[first_card] == cards[second_card]) { 
         alert('win'); } 
    else {
         alert('loose'); }

    exposed[first_card]=false;
    exposed[second_card]=false;
    state=0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Those event handlers in javascript give me a headache.